# How to tell typescript that a variable is now not null?

Tags: typescript

(I'm an old-school C/C++ guy just learning typescript.)

I have some code like this:

```js
class myClass {
  v: string | null = null

  setVtoNonNull() { this.v = "hi" }

  method() {
    if (!this.v)
      this.setVtoNonNull()
    // now at this point v is definitely not null
    // how do I tell typescript that?
    const s: string = this.v // <<<< typescript gives error here
  }
}
```

In `method`, how do I tell typescript that after the `setVtoNonNull()` call, local variable `v` is not null? I know I can use `v!` wherever I use `v` after it's set (but that's annoying if I use `v` a lot), or I could do this horrible hack:

```
   v = v!
```

but that would cost cycles at runtime just for compile-time cleanliness. Is there a compiler directive or something I can use?

Comment: Are side effects in the method required here? If you return the value, have the return type as simply `string`, then reassign at the call site, that might do it.

Comment: TypeScript control flow analysis / type inference almost never goes across function boundary. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20901, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10357, and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: I guess another way is to add an unnecessary `if (v) { ... }` block around the code where I know it's non-null. Typescript will figure out that that means it can't be null in the body of that `if`, right?

Comment: Right, but non-null assertion `const s: string = this.v!` is more explicit than `if` with always true condition IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
class myClass {
    v: string | null = null;

    setVtoNonNull(): string {
        if (!this.v) {
            this.v = "hi";
        }
        return this.v;
    }

    method() {
        const s: string = this.setVtoNonNull();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to cast it to the expected type.

```
    // now at this point v is definitely not null
    // how do I tell typescript that?
    const s: string = this.v as string  // <<<< explicit cast
```

Or use the [Non-null Assertion Operator Postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) (aka "magic punctuation" :-)

```
    // now at this point v is definitely not null
    // how do I tell typescript that?
    const s: string = this.v!  // <<<< "non-null assertion"
```

Answer (score -3):

This kind of defeat's the purpose of Typescript. Anyway, since TypeScript will infer the variable type, I suggest you use something like this

```
class myClass {
  v: any = null
  // ... rest of your conde
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see what you're going for here. How would it be better to disregard type safety altogether and use `any`?