# How can I tell typescript that an object's function will populate an otherwise null property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

My problem is similar to this:

```
Type Name = {firstName: string, lastName: string}

class NameClass {
  public _name: Name | null;

  constructor() {
    this._name = null;
  }

  // or any function
  public set name(name: Name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  public printName() {
    if (!this._name) this.name = { firstName: "should not", lastName: "be null" };
    //          v Object may be null even though I just set it ^
    console.log(this._name.firstName);
  }
}
```

I'm aware I can simply use the " ! " assertion to get around this or can create a separate function to make sure that the object is not null, but I'm looking for a way to tell typescript that the function will set the property.

There is a solution proposed in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769235/how-to-tell-typescript-that-a-variable-is-now-not-null)

but I find this kind of hacky and doesn't really solve the problem. The post was also 4 years ago, so I'm hoping there is a better way to fix this?

Comment: You got a fatal typo. In `printName()` you set `this.name` while your class property is named `_name`. Fix that and TypeScript will actually be able to infer that correctly.

Comment: This does seem to be caused by a typo and will probably be closed as such.

Comment: It is not a typo and works as expected in vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version type checks:

```
type Name = { firstName: string; lastName: string };

class NameClass {
  public _name: Name | null;

  constructor() {
    this._name = null;
  }

  ensureName(): asserts this is { _name: Name } {
    if (!this._name)
      this.name = { firstName: 'should not', lastName: 'be null' };
  }

  // or any function
  public set name(name: Name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  public printName() {
    this.ensureName();
    
    console.log(this._name.firstName);
  }
}
```

but I think using the non-null assertion operator is more idiomatic, and doesn't give you less guarantees, as TS mostly trusts you regarding the `asserts ...` syntax.

Comment: The non-null assertion operator is definitely the best way to do this, but having "!" everywhere really bothered me. That was the answer I was looking for though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered initializing the _name property in the constructor?

```
type Name = {firstName: string, lastName: string}

class NameClass {
  public _name: Name;

  constructor() {
    this._name = { firstName: "should not", lastName: "be null" };
  }

  // or any function
  public set name(name: Name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  public printName() {
    console.log(this._name.firstName);
  }
}
```

Typescript is okay with that, because that way _name is always set.

Comment: This is good but it would be better to move the default value to either a static member of the class or a module-level constant in case the logic of the class requires being able to easily tell the default value from a non-default value. It's also better for perf, although probably not enough to matter.

Comment: Well no, In my actual project I need it to be null sometimes as the property gets updated and reset frequently. This is just an example application of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, the problem is not telling typescript "how to do it" - it is simply not possible. The class cannot and will never know, what nullable property was set in what function (or some other way). The whole point of having a nullable property **is** to have the opportunity to set that property to null. Even after setting the property, it may return back to null (e. g. through another function).

A work around would be having that property set to defalt string values (`""`) in the constructor.

Also as a side-note, it is not recommendet to have a public property start with an underscore. Normally, only `private` fields are named like that.

Comment: I don't need to have the whole class know whether its null or not, just the scope that the set function is called in. I effectively need the function to also act as if I have a function that does this

```
public isNull(name: Name | null) name is null {
     return name === null;
}
```
Also yeah, the underscore is a mistype.